# Java iOS MDM Policies

Tags: java, ios, mdm

I have an mdm server which manages iOS device(s). 
We have completed all the steps for installing an mdm profile on the device. Also we have applied all policies which are applicable to the device and Configurations like Wi-Fi too.

**Question 1:** When we send "allowAppRemoval" as false the device does not apply this policy this raises the non-compliance of the device as this policy is being sent to the device but device does not acknowledge this policy. MDM Reference documentation of Configuration does mention this policy is available.
It describes it as : Optional. When false, disables removal of apps from iOS device.

But after applying policies say i have sent allowCamera and allowAppRemoval both as false and try to fetch all the policies applied on the device using "Restrictions" command. The restrictions only returns the camera policy and all dependents but does not notify the allowAppRemoval at all.

It there a possibility that iOS does not support this policy? I work on iOS 7.1. 
There are many posts which does report this issue but none provide any solution or a resonable answer to it.

**"Update 1":**
Below is the restrictions payload content passed to the device with allowAppRemoval to the device as false

```
<key>PayloadContent</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>PayloadDescription</key>
            <string>MDM Policies</string>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>Restrictions</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.version1.mdm3.configuration.restrictions1</string>
            <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.applicationaccess</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>BB35B1B3-9944-4C43-AD36-27176362AB2A</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>allowAppRemoval</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

This payload is installed as a profile. Below is the console logs

```
Polling MDM server https://mdm-server-url/location for next command.
 mdmd[1120] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Transaction completed. Status: 200
 mdmd[1120] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Attempting to perform MDM request: InstallProfile
 profiled[1121] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Checking for MDM installation...
 profiled[1121] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: ...finished checking for MDM installation.
 profiled[1121] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Beginning profile installation...
 profiled[1121] <Error>: MKBDeviceLockAssertion: MKBDeviceLockAssertion (asserttype:3)
 profiled[1121] <Error>: MKBDeviceGetGracePeriod: MKBDeviceGetGracePeriod() => (0,0,0)
 profiled[1121] <Error>: MKBDeviceGetGracePeriod: MKBDeviceGetGracePeriod() => (0,0,0)
 profiled[1121] <Error>: get_longlongvalue_for_key: failed to get GracePeriod
 profiled[1121] <Error>: get_longlongvalue_for_key: failed to get MaxLifetime
 profiled[1121] <Error>: MKBDeviceSetGracePeriod: MKBDeviceSetGracePeriod(-1,5,-1)
 profiled[1121] <Error>: MKBDeviceSetGracePeriod: MKBDeviceSetGracePeriod: from AKS 0
 keybagd[46] <Error>: 0x243000 __update_system_keybag_block_invoke: Updating System Keybag
 keybagd[46] <Error>: 0x243000 KBUpdateSystemKeyBag: Got opaqueStuff from ondisk keybag
 profiled[1121] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Profile com.version1.mdm3.configuration installed.
 keybagd[46] <Error>: 0x243000 KBUpdateSystemKeyBag: Saved new keybag with result 2371352
 profiled[1121] <Error>: __MKBAssertionFinalize: __MKBAssertionFinalize(0x17d93b50)
 mdmd[1120] <Notice>: (Note ) MDM: Command Status: Acknowledged
```

And when the profile is installed the Restrictions payload on the device displays as: "Don't specify any restrictions"

[image]

**Question 2:** Is there a policy which can block Remove of MDM Payload. We have the "**PayloadRemovalDisallowed**" attribute present for each payload which when set true we cannot remove the profile installed on the device. But this is done only once while installation of the profile on the device.
My scenario is bit different. I want to have a policy which when needed can be made true which will not allow the mdm profile to be removed and when made false mdm profile is applicable to be removed. 
I have referred all the documentation regarding this too, we can have a supervised device, but this a not the requirement. 
In simple terms do we have a policy like allowCamera which when made false blocks the camera and vice versa. I dont want to change the mdm payload installed on the device at all. If this requires a client side implementation then we can skip it too.

Hope i made myself clear.
Thanks.

Comment: <key>allowAppRemoval</key> will only work for Supervised devices. As the device which i was testing was not supervised this policy was not applied to it.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1.

I have no idea. It looks like you aren't only one asking this:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4244061?start=0&tstart=0

Did you check Console to see any errors/warnings?

One crazy idea. May be this restriction is only applicable to supervised devices. They may just forgot to mention it in the documentation.

Question 2.

You can't do it. It's either removable (for non supervised or supervised device) or non removable (supervised devices only).

Comment: Thats right. I have seen the post on the apple discussion forum, no reply on it though :(. Device Console does not show any errors.
Please see "Update 1" for details regarding the console logs and the payload content sent to the device.

Comment: Question 2: will be skipped as there is no provision or rather policy which restricts user to remove mdm payload. We wanted to handle this remotely. There is a provision for the same in WindowsMDM.

Comment: @Samreen: Try to file Apple bug or request technical support from them through a Apple Enterprise dev program (for #1). I am not sure about details of implementation regarding question #2 (I played very little with supervised devices). If you want, try to find MDM related videos for WWDC 2014. They covered this subject a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at Apple Configurator v. 1.6, the setting for allowAppRemoval is for supervised devices only.  I'm pretty sure that the only way to have a supervised device via MDM is for the device to be enrolled in DEP (Apple's Device Enrollment Program).

As for the MDM payload removable problem, as Victor says, the device must be supervised.  Again, DEP is the only option for MDM payloads.

Comment: Thats correct.. both the functionalities work when the device is supervised.